# Global immutable cache instance scala

Tags: scala, caching, functional-programming, immutability, higher-order-functions

I have implemented immutable cache based on twitter [Storehaus Cache](https://github.com/twitter/storehaus/wiki/Storehaus-Cache)

Following is the code

interface

```
trait Cache[K, V] {
    def get(k: K): Option[V]

    def put(kv: (K, V)): (Set[K], Cache[K, V])

    def iterator: Iterator[(K, V)]
}
```

implementation

```
object SenzCache {
    def empty[K, V]: SenzCache[K, V] = SenzCache[K, V](Map.empty[K, V])

    def apply[K, V](m: Map[K, V]): SenzCache[K, V] = new SenzCache[K, V](m)
}

class SenzCache[K, V](m: Map[K, V]) extends Cache[K, V] {

    override def get(k: K): Option[V] = {
        m.get(k)
    }

    override def put(kv: (K, V)): (Set[K], Cache[K, V]) = {
        (Set.empty[K], new SenzCache(m + kv))
    }

    override def iterator: Iterator[(K, V)] = m.iterator

    override def toString: String = m.toString()
}
```

I can use this cache as following way,

```
val c = SenzCache.empty[String, String]
val c1 = cache.put("era" -> "foo")._2
val c2 = c.put("ban" -> "bar")._2

println(c2.get("era"))
```

I wanna keep global instance of this cache in my application. How can I do that(How to keep single instance of this cache globally in the app?, every put returns a new cache)

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the access to the `Cache` constructor and provide a `lazy val instance = new CacheImpl` like in the example below:

```
sealed trait Cache {
   // your cache methods
}

object Cache { 
  private lazy val instance: Cache = new CacheImpl 

  def apply(...) = instance

  private class CacheImpl(...) extends Cache { ... }
}
```

Comment: problem is not with accessing the cache, every 'put' returns a new SenzCache, how can I handle this in the application, I can use `var cache = SenzCache.empty[String, String]` instead of val, but are there any alternative way.